# Java Illegal Argument Exception thrown when opening NetLogo model in Jython

Tags: netlogo, jython-2.7

I am trying to control NetLogo's API using Jython 2.7.0 (on Java 1.8.0_131) running on OS X El Capitan (10.11.6) to run experiments.  In trying to run the following code:

```
import site
site.addsitedir("/Users/nqe/NetLogo/NetLogo 6.0.1/Java/")
import org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace as hw

workspace = hw.newInstance()
workspace.open("models/Sample Models/Earth Science/Fire.nlogo")
workspace.command("set density 62")
workspace.command("random-seed 0")
workspace.command("setup")
workspace.command("repeat 50 [ go ]")
print (workspace.report("burned-trees"))

workspace.dispose()
```

I get the following error:

```
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:264)
at org.nlogo.generate.PrimitiveCache$.read$1(PrimitiveCache.scala:22)
at org.nlogo.generate.PrimitiveCache$.$anonfun$getClassReader$1(PrimitiveCache.scala:26)
at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
at org.nlogo.generate.PrimitiveCache$.getClassReader(PrimitiveCache.scala:26)
at org.nlogo.generate.PeepholeSafeChecker.processClass(PeepholeSafeChecker.scala:49)
at org.nlogo.generate.PeepholeSafeChecker.isSafe(PeepholeSafeChecker.scala:42)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateInstruction(Generator.scala:190)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generateBodyMethod(Generator.scala:124)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator$InstructionGenerator.generate(Generator.scala:99)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator.org$nlogo$generate$Generator$$recurse(Generator.scala:29)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator.$anonfun$recurse$1(Generator.scala:31)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:193)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:193)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator.org$nlogo$generate$Generator$$recurse(Generator.scala:31)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator.$anonfun$generate$1(Generator.scala:25)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:193)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:193)
at org.nlogo.generate.Generator.generate(Generator.scala:25)
at org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.assembleProcedure(CompilerMain.scala:79)
at org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.$anonfun$compile$2(CompilerMain.scala:55)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:378)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
at org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:55)
at org.nlogo.compile.Compiler.compileProgram(Compiler.scala:52)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessModelOpener.openFromModel(HeadlessModelOpener.scala:54)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openModel(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:532)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:499)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
```

In case the "import site" part is not clear, I did the following:

1. Create a jython script to write all .jar files in "/Users/nqe/NetLogo/NetLogo 6.0.1/Java/" to a .pth file.
2. I then placed this .pith file into said the .../Java/ directory with the .jar files.
3. This allows me to access all the .jar dependencies from sys.path when needing to the import various API features of NetLogo.

I can't figure out exactly what causes this error, for in running on python interactive mode, I was able to successfully create a new instance of NetLogo JVM using the hw.newInstance() command (I could see a Java icon pop up when running this code), and the open command threw the appropriate errors if I fail to specify a url, for example.

Because of this, I thought it might have something to do with my JVM not being configured properly, so I tried a few things.

First, I checked that I was able to actually run the java example of controlling NetLogo API in headless mode found here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API.  I was able to run the code given here using these commands:

```
javadir=/Users/nqe/NetLogo/ControlAPI/
netjardir=/Users/nqe/NetLogo/NetLogo\ 6.0.1/Java/netlogo-mac-app.jar

javaname=Example1

javac -cp "${javadir}":"${netjardir}" $javaname.java
java -cp "${javadir}":"${netjardir}" $javaname
```

without changing any JVM settings manually.  Nevertheless, I went ahead and tried changing things in my JVM settings when running the jython code such as the path to docs and extensions, but in particular, to the ./lib directory.  Unfortunately, specifying the following JVM setting:

```
-Djava.library.path=~/JRE/Contents/Home/jre/lib/
```

does nothing to help the cause.  Note that the ~ here is short for being in the NetLogo 6.0.1 directory and that this was the only lib directory I could find.

Finally, I discord this: when I try to run the above jython script when only specifying the path to netlogo-mac-app.jar, I AM NOT ABLE TO IMPORT the headless class stuff.  Hence, the compilation/ running of the java while specifying only this one .jar classpath could possibly be somehow accessing some useful meta-data necessary for NetLogo to work (I don't know if this is possible with my level of Java background).

Upon thinking this, I found a NetLogo.cfg file in ~/NetLogo 6.0.1.app/Contents/Java/ that contains the following info:

```
[Application]
app.name=NetLogo
app.mainjar=netlogo-mac-app.jar
app.version=6.0.1
app.preferences.id=org/nlogo/app
app.mainclass=org/nlogo/app/MacApplication
app.classpath=$APPDIR/../../Java/args4j-2.0.12.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-all-5.0.4.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-all-5.0.4.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-util-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/asm-util-5.0.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/behaviorsearch.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/commons-codec-1.10.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/commons-codec-1.10.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/gluegen-rt-2.3.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/gluegen-rt-2.3.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/httpclient-4.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/httpclient-4.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/httpcore-4.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/httpcore-4.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/httpmime-4.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/httpmime-4.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jcommon-1.0.16.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jhotdraw-6.0b1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jhotdraw-6.0b1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jmf-2.1.1e.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jmf-2.1.1e.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jna-4.2.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jogl-all-2.3.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/jogl-all-2.3.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/log4j-1.2.16.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/log4j-1.2.16.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/macro-compat_2.12-1.1.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/macro-compat_2.12-1.1.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/netlogo-6.0.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/netlogo-6.0.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/netlogo-mac-app.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/parboiled-java-1.1.7.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/parboiled-java-1.1.7.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/parboiled_2.12-2.1.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/parboiled_2.12-2.1.3.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/pegdown-1.6.0.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/pegdown-1.6.0.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/picocontainer-2.13.6.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/picocontainer-2.13.6.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/rsyntaxtextarea-2.6.0.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/rsyntaxtextarea-2.6.0.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/scala-library-2.12.0.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/scala-library-2.12.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/scala-library-2.12.1.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.0.5.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.0.5.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/shapeless_2.12-2.3.2.jar:$APPDIR/../../Java/shapeless_2.12-2.3.2.jar
app.runtime=$APPDIR/../../JRE
app.identifier=org.nlogo.app

[JVMOptions]
-Dnetlogo.extensions.dir=$APPDIR/../../extensions
-Dnetlogo.models.dir=$APPDIR/../../models
-Dnetlogo.docs.dir=$APPDIR/../../docs
-Xdock:name=NetLogo
-Dorg.nlogo.mac.appClassName=org.nlogo.app.App$
-Xmx1024m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true


[JVMUserOptions]

[ArgOptions]
```

This seemed promising, but literally deleting this file had no affect on my ability to run NetLogo by opening the application/ using the Control API with Java method.  As such, I am stumped, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: NetLogo requires that the current working directory, when the JVM starts, be the NetLogo directory.

Comment: @SethTisue Unfortunately, that doesn't do it, but I did decide in the end to just Control the API from Java where I can control JVM settings more explicitly. In doing so, however, I ran across a second minor question that probably doesn't warrant an entire post: can NetLogo run in multiple threads as in BehaviorSpace when controlling the API directly using only the NetLogo API, or must I now as the user control threads with Java explicitly?

Comment: That's a good question — please open a new question on it.

Comment: @Nic you need to control the threads yourself in java